# Can we install Redis via NPM?

Tags: node.js, redis, npm

Is it possible to compile / install a software via NPM?

Let's say I want to install Redis:

```
$ npm install c-redis -g
```

Would it be possible to compile it?

Answer (score 0):

npm install checks for an npm package with that name.
it doesn't install non npm published packages.
each npm package must have a package.json defining that package.
so short answer is no

Comment: Yes I know, but can a NPM package be able to compile Redis source code then run it?

Comment: package redis inside node module and than setup a script in postinstall should do the trick, but what about dependencies? and you will need to download the right version per os and so on.... I don't see the advantage here. lots simpler to use something like docker instead for things like that.

Comment: "it doesn't install non npm published packages" – wrong. It can install packages from git and https links and from Github: http://browsenpm.org/package.json#dependency.winston

Comment: But they must have package.json which is npm standard. Feel free to add proper answer instead

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can. Run:

```
npm install redis
```

but that will only install the Redis client, not the server itself.
Refer to [Redis Quick Start](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart) on how to install ther server.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sorry, this was the answer of one of my colleagues, but I'll do that the next time:)

Comment: @Pavlo This is a vlid answer.

Comment: @ItayGrudev I think the OP meant Redis server, not client

Comment: @GeorgeKagan That doesn't make sense since one of the question tags is `node.js`.